# Correct approach to use JWT in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

i've reviewed some articles and forums to figure out how to implement JWT authentication in my backend. 
the problem is that i've seen different approaches and idk which one is correct.

consider that i've already installed JWT package.
after that some do this:

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'api',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

'guards' => [
    ...

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'jwt',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

and then in Controllers constructor using

```
 $this->middleware('auth:api');
```

to validate user. they say setting  `'driver' => 'jwt'` will make default guard `jwt`. also they use

```
 $token = auth()->attempt($credentials)
```

to validate token. this was first group approach.

second ones never change anything in config/auth.php (no driver change - no gaurd change ...).

they use a middleware in app/Http/Kernel.php (routeMiddleware):

```
'auth.jwt' => \Tymon\JWTAuth\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
```

and when making routes they apply it using a group, like:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth.jwt'], function () {
    Route::get('logout', 'ApiController@logout');

    Route::get('user', 'ApiController@getAuthUser');

    Route::get('products', 'ProductController@index');
    Route::get('products/{id}', 'ProductController@show');
    Route::post('products', 'ProductController@store');
    Route::put('products/{id}', 'ProductController@update');
    Route::delete('products/{id}', 'ProductController@destroy');
});
```

also they use `$jwt_token = JWTAuth::attempt($input)` or `$this->user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();` to get and validate user.

im'm confused with these approaches, should i use jwt as default guard? or i just add it to my packages and use it explicitly?

Comment: Good question. I assumed that people just don't know enough about the topic and just use something they've seen 'works'

Comment: Both of those approaches uses the jwt authentication as a `route middleware`, I'm guessing the second approach has its own "driver" so to speak and doesn't use one of the built-in ones (or maybe it does, but not through the configuration)

Comment: It doesn't really matter in which way you apply the middleware into routes, its still the same thing. That group definition just groups the `routes` and applies the `middleware` into multiple routes at once. First approach attaches that middleware into a singular controller. They just work on different scopes

Comment: In short, both of them propably do the exact same thing, but apply that `middleware` differently as Laravel has multiple methods of doing so.

Comment: tnx for your answer,  it was helpful

Comment: good point, upvoted